# Tomcat deploy error

Tags: tomcat, deployment, file-permissions

When deploying an application with the Tomcat manager I get the following error:

FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /prademo

Tomcat log shows:

INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at '/home//webapps/PRA/META-INF/context.xml' from '/home//webapps/PRA' java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dstefan/webapps/PRA/META-INF/context.xml (Permission denied)

Permission to what? Both PRA and contex.xml have -rwxrwxrwx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer is simple - permision denied means I had to fix the permisions to any of the folders on path to the context.xml file. Should've though twice before posting this question really. Hope someone else will find this useful one day!